# ie wont support dtds in feed cakephp

Tags: cakephp, rss, cakephp-1.3, dtd

Ok I'm trying to create a rss feed with cakephp rss helper for some post of an app. I followed the cakephp book to the letter and it wont work with internet explorer... When I open it with Opera it work but with ie it says "Internet Explorer does not support feeds with DTDs."...

I know microsoft is not supporting dtds because a security thread but how can I fix this issue? The company where I work uses ie by standard so changing the browser is not an option...

here is the code... So you can see there is not a mayor modification in it...

default.ctp

```
echo $this->Rss->header();
if (!isset($documentData)) {
    $documentData = array();
}
if (!isset($channelData)) {
    $channelData = array();
}
if (!isset($channelData['title'])) {
    $channelData['title'] = $title_for_layout;
} 
$channel = $this->Rss->channel(array(), $channelData, $content_for_layout);

echo $this->Rss->document($documentData,$channel);
```

index.ctp

```
 $this->set('documentData', array(
 'xmlns:dc' => 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'));
 $this->set('channelData', array(
 'title' => __("Most Recent Hitos", true),
 'link' => $this->Html->url('/', true),
 'description' => __("Most recent Hitos.", true),
 'language' => 'en-us')); 


 foreach ($posts as $post) {

    $postLink = array(
        'controller' => 'soportes',
        'action' => 'view',
        $post['Soporte']['id']);
    // You should import Sanitize
    App::import('Sanitize');
    // This is the part where we clean the body text for output as the description 
    // of the rss item, this needs to have only text to make sure the feed validates
    $bodyText = preg_replace('=\(.*?\)=is', '', $post['Hito']['actividad']);
    $bodyText = $this->Text->stripLinks($bodyText);
    $bodyText = Sanitize::stripAll($bodyText);
    $bodyText = $this->Text->truncate($bodyText, 400, array(
        'ending' => '...',
        'exact'  => true,
        'html'   => true,
    ));

    echo  $this->Rss->item(array(), array(
        'title' => $post['Hito']['actividad'],
        'link' => $postLink,
        'guid' => array('url' => $postLink, 'isPermaLink' => 'true'),
        'description' =>  $bodyText,
        'dc:creator' => $post['Hito']['user_id'],
        'pubDate' => $post['Hito']['fecha_sugerida']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a very basic level it might be because of the debug level in core.php - cake outputs the render time I think - you could try setting Configure::write('debug', 0); in your controller action to see if it renders in IE? I've had issues with XML / RSS and IE due to this before.